# Trustpilot JSON - Domain ID

Tags: json, integration, trustpilot

I'm trying to integrate Trustpilot reviews into my website with Magento.
Is there any way to get **Trustpilot ID** without buying an upgrade as the solution below doesn't work anymore?

> Your Trustpilot ID can be found on
>   http://b2b.trustpilot.com/Modules/Plugins. Go to Integrations -> JSON
>   Feed. The Trustpilot ID is the number within the feed url, e.g.
>   http://s.trustpilot.com/tpelements/917278/f.json.gz would give ID:
>   917278

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to get the JSON feed to work without upgrading. But the good news is Trustpilot has APIs available to integrate Trustpilot reviews and Trustpilot is looking for Technology partners. Trustpilot's Support team should be able to help you get access to APIs.
Hope that helps.